# How to fix the debug mode bug on chrome in javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

my problem looks like this:

I have an ace editor in my web page, and i need to change his size, here is the code:

```
                var x = event.pageX;
                pageParams = document.body.getBoundingClientRect();
                ace = document.getElementById("fileInfo");

                if (x > pageParams.width * 0.3) {
                    x = parseInt(pageParams.width * 0.3);
                }

                if(x < pageParams.width * 0.2) {
                    x = pageParams.width * 0.2;
                }

                $element.css({
                    left: x + 'px'
                });

                $($attrs.resizerLeft).css({
                    width: x + 'px'
                });


                var w = topContent.clientWidth;
                var oldX = $($attrs.resizerRight).css('left');
                if(oldX.indexOf('px') > -1) {
                    oldX = parseFloat(oldX.substring(0, oldX.length - 2));
                } else {
                    oldX = parseFloat(oldX);
                }

                $($attrs.resizerRight).css({
                    left: (x + parseInt($attrs.resizerWidth)) + 'px'
            //      width: w + (oldX - x) + 'px'
                });

                $('#fileInfo').css({
                    width: ace.clientWidth - (oldX - x) + 'px' 
                })

                editor.resize();
```

The 4 lines at the end are important to me
They say, find the fileInfo id (my ace editor)
Then set the width of it to (ace editor previous width + old position of the cursor - new position of the cursor + 'px' (for I work with pixels)
and the last line is actually the line that allows the ace editor to be resized

I believe, I had no error in my logic, but here comes my problem:

Once i run this code on google chrome and mozilla firefox, my code breaks, and it always reduces the width of my editor, BUT, when I enter the debug mode of the browser (via F12) and make a break point on the same piece of code, the code WORKS then!!!!!!

I cannot believe it, and I have no explanation for it...
With the debug mode and the break points (not without) it works, but without the breakpoints and/or debug mode it does not work....

I hope I made myself clear and that you ll be able to help me...

Thx

Plus:

I found out, once I am not in the debug mode, the oldX is ALWAYS greater then the X variable, but once i enter the debug mode with the breaks, then its like it should be, sometimes greater, sometimes smaller...

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit of a guess work here, but...

Dev tools debug mode my have several effects, one of which is adding some async nature to the the environment. (Basically, your css might not be applied when you do the resize without debug mode to be on). I would try to add some timeout for the resize call. Try this and see if it fixes the problem:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    editor.resize();
}, 20);
```

Comment: I just tried, and its not the case....again, if there are breakpoints, then it works, else id doesnt :(  thx anyway